# What's the meaning of "break through the wall"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a passage taken from an article:

> I took the job at a particularly low point in my life. Me and my girl had a nasty breakup after months of me not just falling, but running headlong into the depths of depression and self-destruction. When she left, **I broke through the wall.** The creeping emptiness I had felt most of my life became a full-blown Nietzschean void. Years of stuffing my feelings into a deep, dark hole finally crushed most of my ability to have feelings at all.

What does *breaking through the wall* mean? Is this literal?

Comment: No. 'Hit rock bottom' is a more common idiom (if 'break through the wall' is actually used often enough to be considered an idiom). I assume the meanings are very similar.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "Lit Crit" interpretation of a creative metaphoric usage.

Comment: I am still not clear as to whether 'breaking through the wall' was a good or a bad thing to have happened. In any event I think it is a case for a psychiatrist!

Comment: @FF I must remember that one.

Comment: @WS2 Yeah, I think it's an abuse of the usual metaphor which leads to a bizarre mixed message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not literal. The author is stretching the metaphor of "running", perhaps past the breaking point.

Avid runners refer to "[breaking through the wall](http://m.runnersworld.com/running-tips/breaking-through-wall)" as a kind of enlightenment-like experience.

Comment: So this is not a common phrase and that it's thought up from the metaphor of "running"?

Comment: It is a common phrase in the context of athletic running, so it extends the metaphor. He says he is not just falling helplessly into depression, but actively running into it, and by "breaking through the wall" he has achieved a new low, in the same way that a runner might use her willpower to overcome exhaustion and pain and finish a race in record time.

Comment: Indeed, this is a very strange use of “breaking through.” It almost always has positive connotations, but it's not used that way here.

Answer (score 1):

The figurative use  of the expression " break trough the wall" used in the passage suggest the break of a limit (the emptiness) and move into a new  territory ( full-blown void) in a crescendo of despair of the narrator.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the general term "breaking through the wall" means to move to a new level.  In context though this might mean moving to enlightenment, severe depression, or whatever.  It adds emphasis in that you are at a certain point and now you have moved past it.  I know test pilots used to refer to the sound barrier as the wall.  And they were constantly trying to get a level up on speed to break through it.  It is all about context though.

Answer (score -1):

For my two cents, 'breaking through the wall' is the least of the language problems, starting with 'Me and my girlfriend...', an accusative case pronoun posing as the subject of the second sentence.

Off-topic creative writing fixes might suggest that the question's target phrase be modified or removed; e.g., "When she left, I broke through the wall of creeping emptiness I had felt most of my life to plunge into a Nietzschean abyss.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with coordinated accusative pronouns as subjects in English. Only a fool would believe a grammatical ‘rule’ that hasn't been followed by anyone for half a millennium.